# How to access a Style outside the code behind file (xaml.cs)?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In code behind (`filename.xaml.cs` file), I can successfully access the static resources like this:

```
TextBlock elm = new TextBlock();
elm.Style = (Style)this.Resources["myStyle"];
```

where `Styles.xaml` is added to `filename.xaml` like follows:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="resources/Styles.xaml" />
</Page.Resources>
```

However, `this.Resources["myStyle"]` doesn't work in `.cs` file that isn't associated with any `.xaml` file. How to access Style.xaml in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`FindResource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findresource(v=vs.110).aspx).

Either using `this` as a `FrameworkElement`:

```
elm.Style = (Style)this.FindResource("myStyle");
```

Or on the [`Application`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.findresource(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
elm.Style = (Style)Application.Current.FindResource("myStyle");
```

Comment: 'this.FindResource()' doens't work either. It works in the codebehind (where `this.Resources[]` also works), but I want to use it a .cs file that isn't associated with any .xaml file.

Comment: @green: What about on the application?

Comment: do you mean, adding `<ResourceDictionary Source="resources/Styles.xaml" />` to App.xaml? note I updated the question for clarification. but, `this.FindResource()` cannot be accessed from my current context.

Comment: No, call `Application.FindResource`. The resource should be available application wide then though.

Comment: From MSDN: `Application.Current.FindResource("UnfindableResource");`

Comment: There is, trust me. Did you use the statement as in the comment above? (Note `Current`)

Comment: thanks, that worked :) would you update your answer to include `Application.Current`?